# Apps only crashing on iPad Air 2 with iOS 9.3.1

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

I have a very strange problem with my iPad Air 2.

The problem is that certain apps crash immediately on launch. I tap the icon, the start screen shows and then the app crashes.
This does not apply to all apps just a few. I have not been able to find a pattern. Even Apple’s own “Remote” app is one of the apps.

If I launch the exact same apps on my iPhone, iPad Air or my iPad Pro they work just fine. I am logged into the same Apple/iCloud account on all devices.

I have tried the following:

- Launching the apps in airplane mode, with/without wifi and with/without bluetooth active.
- Deleting and re-installing the apps in question.
- Deleting, restarting the iPad and then re-installing the apps.
- Reset all the settings and apps on the device restoring from a backup with iTunes.
- Reset all the settings and apps on the device setting it up as a new device. Afterwards I downloaded the apps to the device and attempted to launch them.
- Downloaded the current iOS version (9.3.1) from the developer’s page (IPSW file) and then alt-clicked restore to select the IPSW and really re-install iOS on the device. Installed it as a new device and then downloaded the apps in question.

All attempts have been fruitless and futile. 
Otherwise I could mention, that the iPad is a cellular model and has never been jailbroken.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could still do?
Or is my only hope visiting an Apple Store nearby?

Thanks kindly for any feedback.

PS: I almost forgot the apps in question have never opened correctly on this specific iPad Air 2. My friend's iPad Air 2 can use the apps without any problems. So it does not seem to be a device-type specific bug.

Comment: You've already done everything I would've suggested. Have you looked thru any of the logs using Xcode?  You should be able to see the crash messages from there.

Comment: yes - but these are also not very informative. There are `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` of the `SIGSEGV` (`KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`), `SIGBUS` (`KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE`) and `SIGILL` variety. And all the listed entries are all from core or standard iOS libraries.

Comment: Maybe you have a bad memory chip or something like that?  Based on what you've already tried, can you return the iPhone and exchange it for another one?  I know this is probably the last resort, and hopefully others here can come up with something, but it might be your only option.